# Qt QWebView class custom User-Agent

Tags: qt, qt4

Is there an easy way to setup the User-Agent the QWebView class is using?

The only relevant link I found searching was this

http://www.qtforum.org/article/27073/how-to-set-user-agent-in-qwebview.html

I'm learning C++/Qt right now and I don't really understant what's explained on that website. Maybe someone knows an easy way to do it? Or can help me understand that code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Qt allows you to provide a user agent based on the URL rather than a single user agent no matter what the URL is.  The idea then is to return the user agent any time a new webpage is created:

```
class UserAgentWebPage : public QWebPage {
    QString userAgentForUrl(const QUrl &url ) const {
        return QString("My User Agent");
    }
};
```

In order to use that page instead of the standard page that is created, you can set that page on the browser control object before making the request:

```
yourWebView->setPage(new UserAgentWebPage(parent));
```

I would actually expect a factory to be present somewhere that will guarantee that the webpage created is always of a certain type, but I didn't see one.

Yet another option should be to set the user agent header within the [QNetworkRequest](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qnetworkrequest.html#setHeader):

```
QNetworkRequest request = new QNetworkRequest();
request->setRawHeader(
    QString("User-Agent").toAscii(),
    QString("Your User Agent").toAscii()
    );
// ... set the URL, etc.
yourWebView->load(request);
```

You would actually want to check whether it's `toAscii()` or `toUtf8()` or one of the other variants as I'm not sure exactly what the HTTP standard allows.

Answer (score 2):

simply,

```
class myWebPage : public QWebPage
{
    virtual QString userAgentForUrl(const QUrl& url) const {
        return "your user agent";
    }
};

//Attention here is new myWebPage() not new myWebPage(parent) 
UI->webView->setPage(new myWebPage());
```