# How to fake a connection as if it is coming from Chrome browse

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi, qwebview

I have a C++ application with which I simulate some user clicks on a target website. It works pretty fine for now. However, the target website logs everybody who is connected. Of course they also log what browse you used when connecting. I don't know what they see when I connect from my application but I would like them to see a Chrome browser is connected. Is there any way to do this? I am currently using Qt if it will help to develop your comment.

Thanks.

Comment: Google for user+agent (+fake+qt etc as needed).

Comment: Related: [Qt QWebView class custom User-Agent](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3906964/2802841).

Comment: thanks. i will dig into.